# Sale name 'i' is not defined ¿Qué hago?

Tags: python

LLevo un rato intentando encontrar la solución. Previamente me decía:

```
local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Busqué en internet y puse lo de global i. Pero sigo sin conseguir que funcione

```
def mcm(x,y):
    global i
    for i in range(1,max(x,y),1)== x%i == 0 and y%i == 0:
        return i
```

Comment: Quita `global i`. En este caso no tiene sentido. Sólo se usa si hay una variable global con ese mismo nombre y tu función necesita modiricar su valor. Esto no es el caso aquí, ya que la variable perfectamente puede ser local de la función y en ese caso no es necesario "declararl"

Comment: Vale gracias. Al quitarlo sale: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment y no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: Sí, es que además tenías errores en la sintaxis del `for`, en la que ni me había fijado. La respuesta de Candid Moe te explica cómo arreglarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, el `global i` es innecesario, pues `i` es una variable propia de la función, inicializada en el `for`

Segundo, el formato de `for` es incorrecto; debes separar el `for` que recorre los valores del `if` que los prueba:

```
def mcm(x,y):
    for i in range(2, min(x,y)):
        if x % i == 0 and y % i == 0:
            return i
    return 0
```

Le agregue un `return 0` para cuando los valores no tenga MCM.

También cambie el rango del `for`, pues hay que partir probando con el valor 2. Si pruebas `x % 1` siempre será cero. Por otra parte, el límite superior está dado por `min(x,y)`, no por `max`: en MCM no puede ser mayor que alguno de los dos.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias. Acabo de empezar y todavía me cuesta.